# jquery validation issue with checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Having a problem with jquery validation.  I have two checkboxes... only on the second I am requiring it be checked.

The validation works, however, there are two problems :

1 - if there is an error (2nd box not checked) it removes the `<span>` from the first which is totally unrelated to it... but still shows the error message for the second where it should.

2 - When there is an error on the 2nd... checking it does not remove the error message.  Also, checking and unchecking multiple times causes multiple error messages to be displayed on each 'uncheck'.

**html :**

```
<form id="downloadInstall" method="post" action="/process/p_module_dl.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 margin-bottom-30 form-group">
            <p class="f-15 margin-bottom-15"><b>Select your options :</b></p>
            <div class="checkbox-list">
                <label
                    <input type="checkbox" name="settings[confirm]" value="1"/>
                    <span>Require confirmation during installation?</span>
                </label>
                <span class="help-block">Notifies user software will be installed and requires confirmation before it is installed.span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 margin-bottom-50 form-group">
            <div class="checkbox-list">
                <label for="vdownload-terms">
                    <input id="vdownload-terms" type="checkbox" name="settings[terms]" value="1"/>
                    <span>I agree to the <a data-window="external" href="/terms.php">Terms and Conditions</a>.</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 margin-bottom-50 form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

**js :**

```
$('#downloadInstall').validate({
    errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
    errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
    focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
    rules: {
        'settings[terms]': {
            required: true
        }
    },

    messages: {
        'settings[terms]': {
            required: "You must agree to the Terms and Conditions before downloading."
        }
    },

    highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
        $(element)
            .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },

    unhighlight: function (element) { // un-hightlight error inputs
        $(element)
            .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); 
    },

    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element.closest('.checkbox-list'));
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // do other things for a valid form
        form.submit();
    }

});
```

**Update :**

In the case of the second issue.  Checking and unchecking the checkbox is causing `has-error` to be added/removed to this container, but it does not remove the `<span>` error message - it adds another.  The only thing that happens is the color of all the error messages changes from red when the error class is present to grey which is simply a css style.

```
<div class="col-md-12 margin-bottom-50 form-group has-error">
    <div class="checkbox-list">
        <label for="vdownload-terms">
            <div id="uniform-vdownload-terms" class="checker">
                <span class="">
                    <input id="vdownload-terms" type="checkbox" value="1" name="settings[terms]" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="settings[terms]-error settings[terms]-error settings[terms]-error settings[terms]-error" aria-invalid="true">
                </span>
            </div>
            <span>I agree to the <a href="/terms.php" data-window="external">Terms and Conditions</a>.</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <span id="settings[terms]-error" class="help-block">You must agree to the Terms and Conditions before downloading.</span>
    <span id="settings[terms]-error" class="help-block">You must agree to the Terms and Conditions before downloading.</span>
    <span id="settings[terms]-error" class="help-block">You must agree to the Terms and Conditions before downloading.</span>
    <span id="settings[terms]-error" class="help-block">You must agree to the Terms and Conditions before downloading.</span>
</div>
```

One thing I did not notice until now is that the id is being modified and appears to be due to the use of the uniform plugin. [uniform js](http://uniformjs.com/)

Comment: Your problem description is unclear.  You are describing issues with error messages on two different checkboxes, yet you've only defined validation rules for one of the checkboxes.

Comment: it is because of the error-class, since you have mentioned it as `help-block` it looks like the validator is hiding all elements with the said class....

Comment: look at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b6rbL7ma/2/ - even the very first element also is hidden - so it is testing for both error element and class

Comment: yes... that assumption seems to be correct... look at `$(this.settings.errorElement + "." + errorClass, this.errorContext)` it selects all those elements... then in `prepareForm` there is `this.toHide = this.errors().add( this.containers )`

Comment: @Sparky have you seen this problem before... any solution? other than changing the error element or class

Comment: @user756659 not able to recreate the second issue - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b6rbL7ma/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny, it's bedtime here so I cannot start digging into this now.  I'll review it all in the morning.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Fiddle is not producing the second issue yet on the actual site it happens in both the latest IE and FF.  Couldn't tell you why. I have already tried changing the error element class which solves issue 1, but issue 2 still occurred.

Comment: One potential issue is that you've defined the `errorClass` as `.help-block` but you're setting and unsetting `.has-error` with custom `highlight` & `unhighlight` functions.  Typically, `highlight` & `unhighlight` toggle the classes by their builtin keywords, `errorClass` and `validClass`.  You are completely over-riding the default behavior when you use these callback functions.  See the source code of the plugin.

Comment: The Validate plugin does not use `id` so you have to see what's happening to the original element and it's `name` attribute.  Yes, if you are hiding the default element and using `uniform` to recreate it, you have to manually capture the click/change event and do a validation test.  Create a jsFiddle demo that shows your issue.

Comment: Actually it does - http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/ - note they recommend using the label for and id for its input.  As for the name of the input this never changes.

Comment: The documentation is ambiguous.  It is merely telling you that forms typically have `id` and `name` set to the same value and the `for` attribute refers to the input's `id`.  However, there is no requirement that you use an `id` or that you even have a `label`... the only requirement is that each data input contain a unique `name`.  These facts are confirmed by experience and by examining the plugin's source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue with some help/advice from above...

```
//errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
errorClass: 'help-block f-13', // default input error message class
focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
```

Everything else is the same.  I commented out using span as the errorElement... this defaults to the error messages showing in a label which also eliminates all the issues I had.  I added f-13 class to my errorClass which simply styles the font to 13px (since the messages are now in labels the font size of my labels was larger).

End result looks and acts exactly the same minus the problems.

Comment: This answer makes absolutely no sense whatsoever, unless the `uniform` plugin somehow steps all over the `<span>` created by Validate.  I really wish you would have created a jsFiddle demonstrating the issue.  We could have gotten to the root of this.

Comment: There is a fiddle listed above with everything minus uniform included.

Comment: Are you talking about the jsFiddle created by @Arun which wasn't able to fully reproduce the issue?  (probably because it doesn't include `uniform`)

Comment: Yes... that had my same info. I added uniform to that the other day and couldn't reproduce the error.  I have no idea why, but I know that using the default errorClass instead of span solved all my issues.